# How to update a record without changing rowversion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rowversion

If a table has a rowversion column in it and you make an update to that row, the value of the rowversion column increases.  I know that this is by design and the purpose of rowversion columns, however is there any way to make it such that an update operation will have no effect on rowversion value?

Edit:  Tracking of updates on all columns is required, however there are some operations that we would like to avoid being perceived as new versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx). "Every time that a row with a rowversion column is modified or inserted, the incremented database rowversion value is inserted in the rowversion column."

Answer (score 3):

No, but perhaps you mean to use [auto-increment](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=41676)?  Then you have a new unique number when the row is created but it doesn't change when the row is updated.

If you also wanted some kind of change-counter that didn't apply to all columns you could then implement that yourself in another column.